# fixed div with horizontal scroll css

Tags: css, html, scroll, fixed

I'm doing a horizontal layout and I want the header to scroll horizontally .. I show you an example of code css.

```
body {  
    background-color:#fff;  
}

#container {  
    margin:30px auto;  
    width:3000px;  
    height:700px;  
    border:1px dotted #ccc;  
}

#header {
    position:scroll;  
    margin:20px 20px;  
    width:200px;  
    height:70px;  
    border:1px dotted #999;  
}
```

thank you

Edit:

yeah..thank you so much..problem solved!!!

Comment: can you please put this in jsfiddle.net so we can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `position:scroll`, what I'm guessing you're looking for is `position:fixed` for your header, but be aware that this won't work for IE6, though.

A small sample to show you: http://jsbin.com/ihuma3/edit

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution, really: You just need to change your "position:scroll;" to "overflow:scroll;".

To make this only scroll horizontally, change it to: "overflow-x:scroll;".

Hope that helps!